# Laravel 5.1 $request->all() add an activation_code

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I need help in Laravel 5.1 $request->all(). I am trying to create a user and I am using UserRegistrationRequest to validate my registration form inputs. All are working fine but I need the add an activation code to my activation_code column in users table. How can I add that in the

```
User::create($request->all());
```

Any clean approach?

Answer (score 1):

I found a much cleaner way

```
$user = User::create(array_add($request->all(), 'activation_code', str_random(60)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the activation code to the array:

```
$data = $request->all();
$data['activation_code'] = $activation_code;
User::create($data);
```

Comment: Is there shorthand for that? like array_add()?